# Deploy WCF service with database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I've created an ASP.NET MVC4 project in Visual Studio 2013 and I've created and attached a local database using SQL Server Express. I will deploy this project to a Cloud service, how do you publish the database to Cloud service?

Regards,
Roger

EDIT: I have created my Database using Visual Studio 2013 in Server Explorer Window, right click on Data Connections and Create New SQL Server Database... after connect successful this database in my project on localhost. Now, I have deployed my project to Azure Cloud Service, but How do I upload the database in the same Azure Cloud Service?

**EDIT 2**: I've created my database in App_data, on localhost works fine but when I deploy to Cloud Service, shows the following error when program calls the database:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified).

My connection String is:

```
this.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MidSapDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you right click on the project you should see publish. Click on publish it will take you to a page where you shall able to configure IIS, database etc. Please let me know if you know more details. It should be very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for reply, qamar, Yes, but I've deployed my project using Windows Azure Cloud Service Project, so, How I upload database to use in the cloud service? I think that is a easy thing, but I could not found anywhere.

Comment: Please open sql server management studio. Then connect to your local database server and the database. Then right click on the database name and choose task. Under task you should see "Deploy to Sql Azure" or something similar. Click on that. From there on it should be pretty simple. Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: Well, I don't have Sql Server Management Studio installed because I'm working in a temporal VM, but I don't want to upload database in Azure. I want upload my database with my web application because this web application needed store temporary data. I've created my database with Visual Studio 2013, on Server Explorer, right click on Data Connections and choose New Sql Server Database. Now, I need to publish this database with my project in Cloud Service. I've deployed my project, but how do I upload my database?

Comment: If you database is in app_data folder it should have been deployed already unless you exclude that while deploying the application.

Comment: Oks, How I put database in App_Data folder?

Comment: when you have generated database via sql server it should have gone to app_code folder. Check you app_code folder. Usually file under this folder is hidden, you need to turn on show all files in solution explorer. Check if the database is there or not?

Comment: If I show all files in project, doesn't exist App_Code folder and App_Data exists but is empty. I will try to create new sql database and include .mdf into App_Data folder.

Comment: * sorry I meant app_data folder not app_code. Yes please create a db in app_code. But I suggest you do create a sql express database in your target server. Database migration in subsequent release will be much easier for you this way.

Comment: Well, I've created my database in App_data, on localhost works fine but when I deploy to Cloud Service, shows the following error when program calls the database:  "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) ". Is the connection String wrong?

Comment: that's because your cloud server might not have sql express installed. You need to have sql express or a sql instance running in order to be able to run the local db

Comment: From my knowledge, Azure Cloud Services aren't persistent, the SO data is often deleted. Is it true?

Comment: Well, after being read documentation, I've learned that the Azure WebRole/WorkerRole aren't persistents, for this reason can't install sql express inside. The best way to load/store data is using Azure Database. For any case, If you need load/store a little dataset, you can use SQL Server CE. That's all, @qamar, many thanks to help me for find a solution!